# Terminate Logcat's -f output via shell on Android device

Tags: android, shell, logcat

I am currently running `logcat -v time -f /dir/to/file.log` on an embedded Android device. Everything is running successfully and the log is piped to the file `file.log`.

However, I am unable to terminate logcat's piped output to the file. I am aware of CTRL C, but I am looking for a String based command that can be interpreted via Android's `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` method.

My aim is to terminate the stream of data written to `file.log`. No other condition applies.

Comment: Did you consider calling destroy() on your Process object?

Comment: @JoxTraex Interesting, I will attempt this now and give feedback.

Comment: @JoxTraex Thank you for your input. I have attached exec() with a Process variable and called destroy() after a few seconds, which effectively terminated the stream. Is there a way I can accept this as an answer, or an up-vote?

Comment: Good to hear! I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you consider looking at Process's documentation? I would figure `destroy()` should work for you.

### ref

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Process.html